# EF Core 6 Group By Issue For Multi table join

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, ef-core-6.0

So in our project targeting old .net framework 4.7.1 we have a query like this :

```
var query = from c in context.Table1 join d in context.Table2 on c.enId=d.enId
            join v in context.Table3 on d.sId = v.sId
            group new {c,Name=d.Name,Email=d.Name,v=v.DocumentId} by new{c.enId,CDate=c.DialledDateTime} into grp
ordeby grp.Key.CDate select grp;
```

which was running without issue

now the same query when we upgraded our project to dotnet 6 and ef core 6 is giving below exception

> could not be translated. Additional information: Translation of 'Select' which contains grouping parameter without composition is not supported. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'.

How to solve this , so the same result as earlier can be obtained in dotnet 6 efcore 6 ?

Comment: Tip: The point of EF and a correctly-schema'd database with relationships, foreign keys and the like is that you _don't have to use SQL-like syntax (even if it is LINQ)_.  Just use _navigation properties_.  e.g. `context.Customers.Orders.OrderLine`.   This is why ORMs were invented in the first place.   Also, you can easily shoot yourself in the foot performance-wise with an incorrect LINQ syntax.  If you find you are writing complex queries you might be better off with a stored-proc where it can be optimised by the RDBMS.  All is not lost however as EF still allows invoking of SPs

Comment: Can you show the expected SQL query?

Comment: @vernou whenever i tried to debug at that query line in old project debugger give some weird exception causing not to view the generated sql

Comment: I don't understand the syntax in the example, but if you show the expected query, maybe I will understand... maybe.